# Media Keys suddenly not working?

Tags: windows-8, audio, keyboard

The <kbd>Play/Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Stop</kbd>, <kbd>SkipForward</kbd> and <kbd>SkipBackward</kbd> keys on my CM Quickfire TK keyboard have suddenly stopped working. These keys were working before, I don't know what has changed to make them not work.

All other special function keys such as mute and volume control still work correctly. I believe these other keys work because they control the OS volume, and do not send commands to applications.

These media keys do not work in any media player I have tried (FB2K, VLC, MPC).

I have already tried using the method described [here](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/windows-other-os-discussion-support/220562-windows-8-media-keys-do-not-work.html), to no result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried installing the drivers from the manufacturer?

Comment: There are no drivers - it is a simple keyboard.

Comment: Do you have the Fn lock on or off? See [the manual](http://www.coolermaster.com.cn/gaming/quickfire_tk_user_guide_en.pdf). The first section describes the locking function for the function keys.

Comment: It does not work with the function lock either on or off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happened to me recently with my work Dell keyboard.  The culprit was the Google Play Music browser extension for Chrome.  I disabled it, and my media keys are now working with Windows Media Player on Windows 8.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from happening other than uninstallation? I use the extension to upload music, but I don't actually use it to play music. 

And most likely more extensions will start hijacking the media keys in the future - so we should have some workaround.

Comment: @MarkLopez If you open the extensions page, there's a Keyboard Shortcuts link at the bottom.  Then for Google Music there's options whether you want the shortcuts for Global or for Chrome only.  Choose Chrome only.

Comment: If you are like me and switch between Google Music and WMP, you can simply disable the extension while you want to use WMP.